# Pathname conditional rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I conditionally add a component to the render on certain `pathname`?

Using `const pathname = this.props.location.pathname` I identify the current `pathname`

Then I `get` the `slugs` of the pages I want to identify using

```
const specialPages = get(this.props, 'data.allContentfulSpecialPages.edges')
```

I then organise the returned `data` by

```
const special = specialPages.map(({ node: page })=> (
     `/parent/${page.slug}`
))
```

and this returns the page `slugs` as

```
["/parent/page1", "/parent/page2", "/parent/page3", "/parent/page4", "/parent/page5", "/parent/page6"]
```

All seems good to now but when I try to add add

```
let PageHeader;
    if (pathname !== special) {
      PageHeader =
      <Header/>;
    } else {
      PageHeader = null
    }
```

it doesn't do remove the `<Header/>` for `pathname` identified in `special`

Have I not correctly defined each in the `array`?

**Edit - I have just noticed the issue but unsure of the fix.**
`const special` is returning as `/parent/page1/parent/page2/parent/page3/parent/page4/parent/page5/parent/page6`

When adding to `console.log(special)` I receive

```
0:"/parent/page1"
1:"/parent/page2"
2:"/parent/page3"
3:"/parent/page4"
4:"/parent/page5"
5:"/parent/page6"
length:6
__proto__: Array(0)
```

So I believe I need to `map` these differently.

Comment: Please share the complete code.So others can help.If you share the code in codesandbox it will help others.

Comment: I would love to @Vishnu but it's quite the task to do so. I think I explained it well enough for someone to spot any mistake or missed step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to conditionally add a component to the render based on pathname. A common pattern I've seen for this is to use the and operator with the condition you're looking to check and the component to render if need be.  Something like this.

```
{{ pathname !== special && <Header/> }}
```

This will not display anything if the condition is not true and will display Header component if condition is true.

Comment: Thank you James, you are correct. Whilst, I shall definitely be using this simpler method to conditionally add the component, I am still not getting the mapping of `special` working. If does not seem to be defining the pages as an array as per my edit in the question. Any suggestions as to what I have done wrong?

Comment: Oh sorry didn't realize your problem was more on the "Special" side.  I'm honestly a little confused as to what you're trying to do.  You are comparing above to see if pathname === special, which is comparing a string to an array, which will not be true.  Additionally, your map function does seem off.  If you are deconstructing the parameter object in the arrow function, the syntax seems off.  Are you looking to deconstruct two properties node and page?  If so, the syntax would be { node, syntax}.  If not, can you clarify more for me?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let's say I do not want the `header` to display on `path` `/parent/page1`. Using your method I could do `{{ pathname !== "/parent/page1" && <Header/> }}` but if I wanted to the `header` to not display on an `array` of paths - how should I define this as `special` where `const special = specialPages.map(({ node: page })=> (
     "/parent/${page.slug}"
))` doesn't work?

Comment: If you're "special" array is correct then use the includes method on the special array to if the current path is included in there or not.  ex. `special.includes(pathname)`.  That make sense?

Comment: Sorry, not following?

Comment: `pathname !== special` is comparing a string to an array.  What you really want to do is check if the pathname is one of the strings in the 'special' array.  To check if a string is in a string array, you can use Array.includes().  So instead you should use `special.includes(pathname)` inside of your if statement.  For reference, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes That make any more sense?